# Get wrong output path in webpack file loader

Tags: svg, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I can't get webpack (3.10) file-loader paths to work how I need it.. Here is an extract of my webpack.config.js

```
// ...

const images = {
  test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'images/[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
    },
  },
}

//...

const config = {
  entry: {
    App: './public/assets/js/main.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'assets', 'dist'),
    filename: 'main.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [javascript, styles, images],
  },
  plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin('main.css'), uglify],
}

//...
```

I want my images to be in `/public/assets/dist/images/XXX.svg` but they're beeing loaded into `/public/assets/dist/images/public/assets/images/XXX.svg`

I really don't get it... thank you for every help.

Comment: you can use as `test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/, use: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=./images/'`

Comment: It works! Thank you Pravesh.

Comment: @PraveshKhatri Thanks! You really should turn your comment to answer so people could A. Be more sure that this question was answered. B. Thank you :) Also, you can link to the [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader#examples)

Comment: @MoshFeu I am glad if it help you. I've added as an answer

Comment: @FNGR Happy to help. Now you got an anwer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've already commented. But every question should have an answer.

```
test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
use: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]&outputPath=./images/'
```